# rosbag results in OSError

Tags: rosbag, macos, macos-lion, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello all,
I'm trying to run [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/Recording%20and%20playing%20back%20data), but rosbag fails to record data. I tried both the specified instructions

```
rosbag record -a
```

as well as recording a single topic

```
rosbag record /turtle1/command_velocity
```

but either results in the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mrath/ros/ros/bin/rosbag", line 35, in <module>
    rosbag.rosbagmain()
  File "/Users/mrath/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 807, in rosbagmain
    cmds[cmd](argv[2:])
  File "/Users/mrath/ros/ros_comm/tools/rosbag/src/rosbag/rosbag_main.py", line 115, in record_cmd
    os.execv(recordpath, cmd)
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I'm running ROS in OS X Lion, which I suppose is the problem, but I have no clue to the solution, so please advise.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10969/rosbag-results-in-oserror/) by [mrath](https://answers.ros.org/users/975/mrath/) on ROS Answers with karma: 100 on 2011-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2011-11-08**:
The most up-to-date instructions now live at: http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/OSX/Homebrew

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-22**:
This: https://github.com/wjwwood/ros-osx/tree/master/electric-lion-homebrew is currently the best approach at getting ROS working on Lion.  Many tools are still not working, so use at your own risk.  I would suggest a Ubuntu VM for now.

**Comment by [mjcarroll](https://answers.ros.org/users/9/mjcarroll/) on 2011-08-22**:
Have you followed the guide to date for OSX Lion?  It is currently very unstable, and would probably not make the best platform to learn on until it stabilizes a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This error probably means that rosbag has not been built properly.  The most likely cause of the error is because rosbag/bin/record does not exist.

---

Originally posted by [kwc](https://answers.ros.org/users/11/kwc/) with karma: 12244 on 2011-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1